# Making a random number divisible by 10

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, random

I know making a random number divisible by 10 means it isn't so random after all, but stick with me. Imagine a game grid of tiles that are 10x10 pixels. I want to place a 10x10 sprite randomly on the game grid.

I've got everything working other than getting my random number function to return random numbers that are divisible by 10. If I give it a range of 10 and 50, I want it to only return 10, 20, 30, 40, 50. You know what I mean.

Here's my function:

```
public function randomNumber(low:Number = 0, high:Number = 1):Number
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + high - low)) + low;
}
```

How can I make that happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Generate a number from 1-5 and multiply it by 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

generate a random number from 1 to 5 and multiply by 10.

Answer (score 1):

Like he^ said above, generate a random value between 1 and 5, then multiply by 10.

```
return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + high - low)) + low) * 10;
```